# make modules_install fails with depmod looking in wrong path when installing from build directory

Tags: makefile, build, linux-kernel

I went through the following steps to try and build the Linux kernel in a dedicated build directory and then install it in another local directory:

- Copied Linux kernel source tree to `~/linux`
- Ran `make mrproper` and `git pull`ed 'master' branch from kernel.org
- Created an empty `build` directory
- Copied an old config to `build/.config` and ran `make O=build oldconfig` to update, keeping default values for all new config options.
  This updated the file `build/.config`.
- Compiled the kernel with `make O=build`
  This worked fine and populated my `build` dir with compiled output.
- Created empty `install` directory and set it as install path

```
~/linux> mkdir install
~/linux> export INSTALL_PATH=../install
~/linux> export INSTALL_MOD_PATH=../install/modules
```

- Installed the kernel with `make O=build install`
  This placed `System.map` and `vmlinuz` in the `install` directory.
- Tried to install kernel modules with:

```
~/linux> make O=build modules_install
[...]
  SYMLINK ../install/modules/lib/modules/6.6.0-1-default+/build
  INSTALL ../install/modules/lib/modules/6.6.0-1-default+/modules.order
[...]
  INSTALL ../install/modules/lib/modules/6.6.0-1-default+/kernel/virt/lib/irqbypass.ko
  DEPMOD  ../install/modules/lib/modules/6.6.0-1-default+
depmod: ERROR: could not open directory /home/gabe/linux/build/../install/modules/usr/lib/modules/6.6.0-1-default+: No such file or directory
depmod: FATAL: could not search modules: No such file or directory
```

Note that the path in the error message includes a `usr` directory between the first `modules` and `lib` where the path used to install the earlier files does **not** include that.

IOW, `make modules_install` seems to be looking in the wrong place at this stage in the process. It installs a bunch of files in `${INSTALL_MOD_PATH}/lib/modules/...`, but then tries to look up a subdirectory of `${INSTALL_MOD_PATH}/usr/lib/modules/...`.

To make sure that the problem is not caused by using a relative path name, I also tried with an absolute path:

- Removed `install` directory and recreated it empty
- Tried absolute paths:

```
~/linux> export INSTALL_PATH=/home/gabe/linux/install
~/linux> export INSTALL_MOD_PATH=/home/gabe/linux/install/modules
```

- Installed kernel with `make O=build install`.
  This worked as before and placed `System.map` and `vmlinuz` in `install` directory.
- Tried to install kernel modules again with:

```
~/linux> make O=build modules_install
[...]
  SYMLINK /home/gabe/linux/install/modules/lib/modules/6.6.0-1-default+/build
  INSTALL /home/gabe/linux/install/modules/lib/modules/6.6.0-1-default+/modules.order
[...]
  INSTALL /home/gabe/linux/install/modules/lib/modules/6.6.0-1-default+/kernel/virt/lib/irqbypass.ko
  DEPMOD  /home/gabe/linux/install/modules/lib/modules/6.6.0-1-default+
depmod: ERROR: could not open directory /home/gabe/linux/install/modules/usr/lib/modules/6.6.0-1-default+: No such file or directory
depmod: FATAL: could not search modules: No such file or directory
```

Same problem, but with an absolute path.

Am I doing something wrong? Is this expected, or could it be an actual bug somewhere in the machinery of `make modules_install`?

Comment: FWIW, I tried again without using a dedicated build directory, i.e. all the compiled output landed directly in the source tree, and the result was the same.


As a workaround, one can `cd` into `$INSTALL_MOD_PATH` and create a symlink like so:
```ln -s . usr```


After that, `make modules_install` works fine and finishes successfully.

Comment: I also tried setting `MODLIB` directly, which should override `INSTALL_MOD_PATH` entirely, according to docs (`Documentation/kbuild/kbuild.rst`), but that only lead to a bunch of messages like:
```
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/lib/modules/6.6.0-...: Permission denied
```
... clearly indicating that `MODLIB` was completely ignored.

Comment: Following a hunch that `INSTALL_MOD_PATH` perhaps needs to be defined at kernel configuration time already, I made sure both it and `INSTALL_PATH` were set correctly, re-ran `make O=build oldconfig` (no change to `.config`), then the compile step with `make O=build`, then `make O=build install` (worked as before) and finally `make O=build modules_install`, but with the same result as before.

Comment: For a lark, I tried a completely new build in a separate build dir with a new config running
`mkdir build2`, `make O=build2 tinyconfig`, `make O=build2`, `make O=build2 install` and finally `make O=build2 modules_install` (all from `~/linux`, the source tree base dir) and this actually *worked fine*!

I have to wonder, though, whether it's only due to the tiny config, which perhaps does not trigger whatever step usually raises the error...

Comment: I tried again (from the same source tree) with the following commands: `mkdir build3`, `mkdir install3`, `export INSTALL_PATH="../install3"`, `export INSTALL_MOD_PATH="../install3/modules"`, `make O=build3 localmodconfig`, `make O=build3`, `make O=build3 install` and finally `make O=build3 modules_install` and I got the same result. So it's clearly related to the config in some way, but it happens even if the env vars are set from the beginning.